# How do I dynamically change link tags in header based on region in Django CMS

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-cms

I'm looking for a way to change link tags with hreflang depends on region or language used on a site. For example:

I have one blog site written in english and on this site I would like to have:

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com" />`

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com/de" />`

And for German version:

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="https://example.com/de" />`

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com" />`

I could do that with statements like this:

`{% if request.build_absolute_uri == "https://example.com" %}`

`{% if request.build_absolute_uri == "https://example.com/de" %}`

but what if I will have more then these two paths and my if statement will grow. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is inspired by the django cms [language_chooser](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/50dee524a1789d2259d760ba6726072907bad36b/menus/templatetags/menu_tags.py#L362) template tag.

You write your own [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) like this:

```py
from cms.utils.i18n import (
    get_language_list
    get_language_object,
    get_public_languages
)
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.utils.translation import get_language


def language_list_processor(request):
    """
    A context processor that adds the available languages to the global context.
    """
    context = {}
    site = Site.objects.get_current()
    if request.user.is_staff:
        languages = get_language_list(site_id=site.pk)
    else:
        languages = get_public_languages(site_id=site.pk)
    language_info = []
    for language in languages:
        obj = get_language_object(language, site_id=site.pk)
        languages_info.append({"code": obj['code'], "name": obj['name']})

    context['languages'] = languages_info
    context['current_language'] = get_language()
    return context
```

With this context processor in place, you'll be able to access those context variables in your template and loop over them to create your link tags with the respective `hreflang`.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will help me. I need to analyze it more because I'm new to Django and Python :) Did not use context yet, but I will bind this somehow with my base.html and code!

Thanks for the quick answers